# HTML5 geolocation tracking - responding to geo tracking popup close in IE

Tags: html, geolocation

I'm using HTML5 tracking geo-location feature in my SPA. All is working fine, except for in IE11 and IE Edge, when you close the pop-up which asks whether to allow or block geo tracking, it doesn't call the error call back of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError, options);`

Therefore none of the functionalites thereafter does not take place. Here's my implementation:

```
   if (window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation) {
  window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      this.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
      this.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
      this.storeGeoCodeSettings(this.latitude, this.longitude);

    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.message);
      this.getGeoInfoFromExtApi();
    }, {
      timeout: 5000
    }
  );
}
```

Note that this only happens if you close the pop-up without actually responding with accept or reject, but I would expect the reject behavior to fire, if I close the popup. What should I do?